# ¿como remover o reemplazar variables repetidas de una dirección url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una función js que captura el name y el value de uno o mas checkbox y los concatena como una variable a una dirección url, necesito hacer que esa misma función busque si esa variable ya existe en la ulr y en caso de que exista la reemplace o la remueva para que no se repita en la url. He aqui la funcion:

JS

```
$('#form-filter').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

if (window.location.href === 'http://localhost/tienda-poo/') {
    var url = 'http://localhost/tienda-poo/categoria/filtro';
}else{
    var url = window.location;
}

var checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox:checked');

  checkboxs.forEach((checkbox, index) => {
    if (index == 0) {
      url += ('&' + checkbox.name + '=' + checkbox.value);
    } else {
      url += ('&' + checkbox.name + '=' + checkbox.value);    
    }
  });

  window.location = url;

  console.log(url);
});
```

Comment: ¿Porqué habrían de estar repetidas? ¿Los checkbox se repiten?

Comment: si, hay mas de un checkbox con el mismo name.

Comment: Si hay mas de un `checkbox` con el mismo `name`, ¿no deberías crear un arreglo? Cuando lei tu pregunta pense que las variables repetidas estaban en `url` ya que es igual a `window.location`  y podría tener `query params`

Comment: Si los checkbox se repiten hay un problema de diseño. ¿Qué sentido tiene un checkbox duplicado?

Comment: @MauricioContreras, si se intenta mandar una variable con múltiples valores, lo que se hace es definirla como arreglo (`eg: <input name="colores[]" value="negro">, etc`) lo que no es un error. Un ejemplo de uso seria un "multiple choise"

Comment: marcos, ¿como podría modificar mi función para definiría como arreglo?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar [`.serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

#### Ejemplo

```js
$('#form-filter').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (window.location.href === 'http://localhost/tienda-poo/') {
    var url = 'http://localhost/tienda-poo/categoria/filtro';
  } else {
    var url = window.location.href;
    let pos = window.location.href.indexOf('?');
    if (pos >= 0) {
      // Removemos TODOS los parametros anteriores
      url = url.substr(0, pos);
    }
  }

  url += '?' + $(this).serialize();
  console.log(url);

  //window.location = url;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-filter">
  Pintar: <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="pintar" value="si" checked />
  <br/>
  Colores:
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="colores[]" value="negro" checked /> Negro |
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="colores[]" value="blanco" checked /> Blanco <br/>
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: hola probé tu función y me esta agregando estos caracteres: %5B%5D a la url antes del igual, ejemplo: http://localhost/tienda-poo/categoria/filtro&id_genero%5B%5D=2

Comment: @jmz, esos caracteres son el `[` y el `]` codificados en `URL`.

Comment: ¿hay alguna forma de evitar que se codifiquen en la url?

Comment: @jmz, ¿porque habrías de querer hacer eso? esa es la forma correcta de enviar dichos caracteres vía URL.

Comment: lo siento no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre js o jquery, pasa que si envió la url con los [ ] codificados, la lógica de mi controlador no los interpreta y entonces el método no funciona como es debido, intentare ver que puedo hacer al respecto.

Comment: @jmz ¿podrías compartir de alguna forma el código tu controlador? como para poder entender donde esta el problema. También podrías crear una nueva pregunta planteando este problema

Comment: me imagino que mi problema es el .htaccess que no esta permitiendo añadir brackets. aquí el código:<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Activar Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/tienda-poo/error/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</ifModule>

Comment: @jmz, si usas `PHP` en tu `backend`, podrías usar [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php) para obtener los datos en el formato correcto.